# how to remove offset in responsive mode in bootstrap 4

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have a very simple set up in place, that looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div id="whoarewe" class="offset-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"></div>
        <div id="whatwedo" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 cold-sm-12 col-xs12>
        </div>
 </div>
```

The thing is, in responsive mode, the id #whoarewe still has the 2 column offset, therefore is not lined up vertically with #whatwedo. Is there any way I can do this with simply a `media query`? or is there a bootstrap property that would take care of it in col-xs and col-sm?

I tried to set `col-lg-offset-2` and `col-sm-offset-0` but this didn't work :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution that works in my case, basically using a `row` property called `justify-content-around` like so:

```
<div class="row justify-content-around">
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-log-4></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="whoarewe" class="col-md-4 offset-md-2"></div>
    <div id="whatwedo" class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Refer to the documentation for correct offset classes:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

Otherwise you can set the column width and do some flex magic by justifying content as per your need

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content